# This is not a valid Subversion Repository: svn: E210004: Handshake failed, received: ''

Tags: svn, subversive, bamboo

**This is not a valid Subversion Repository: svn: E210004: Handshake failed, received: ''**

```
URL=svn://X.X.X.X:XX/svn/project/default-pom/trunk
```

Does someone already face this problem?
Thanks for all suggestions

Comment: That looks like a configuration setting - but where? Subversive? Bamboo? What are you doing to generate that error? Running a command? Updating configuration, etc? Is that url a valid repo? Have you confirmed that by checking it out directly with svn? What other tests have you done?

Comment: From bamboo, i want to create a plan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across (and cracked :-) ) the same problem with Eclipse Kepler, Subclipse 1.6.x, and a Synology NAS. You may need to make sure that "svnserve" is in the /usr/bin of the SVN **server**.

There are two tests you can do to check this:

1) On the SVN **client** machine, type:

> svn list --verbose svn+ssh://SVNServerLogin@SVNServerIP:pathOfSVNrepo

2) On the SVN **server** machine, type:

> ls /usr/bin | grep svnserve

If you can't find the link in /usr/bin and the "svn" command returns an error (such as "sh: svnserve: not found"), I recommend the following command as root on the SVN **server**:

> ln -s /opt/bin/svnserve /usr/bin/svnserve

(I found my svnserve in /opt/bin, but of course it might be in a different location in your case).

Sorry if I'm a couple of years late to answer your question!

Best.

Comment: This helped me, although I did in fact have svnserve in /usr/bin. However, I had screwed up $PATH for non-interactive ssh sessions, so the ssh command would search in the wrong location.